# Find the joint distribution with 2 discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

How do you find the following joint distribution P(X=r, Y=k)? So far I have gotten:

P(X=0, Y=0) = (0.4)(0.8) = 0.32

P(X=1, Y=1) = (1-0.4)(0.9) = 0.54

How do I go on to find P(X=0, Y=1)and P(X=1, Y=0)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$P(X=0,Y=1)+P(X=0,Y=0)=P(X=0)$

Comment: Then P(X=1,Y=0) + P(X=1,Y=1) = P(X=1)? Are my calculations for P(X=0, Y=0) and P(X=1, Y=1) correct also? Thanks.

Comment: Your calculations are correct. If you have found $P(X=0,Y=1)$ then you can find $P(X=1,Y=0)$ also. This by means of $P(X=0,Y=0)+P(X=0,Y=1)+P(X=1,Y=0)+P(X=1,Y=1)=1$. (Or the method you propose yourself).

Comment: How do I find P(Y=0) so I can use P(X=0,Y=0) = P(X=0) x P(Y=0) to see if X and Y are independent?

Comment: $P(Y=0)=P(X=0,Y=0)+P(X=1,Y=0)$.

Comment: P(Y=0) = 0.32 + 0.06 = 0.38, P(X=0) x P(Y=0)= 0.4 x 0.38 = 0.152, P(X=0,Y=0) = 0.32. They aren't equal, so X and Y are not independent.

Comment: They are indeed not independent. Other route: if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $P(Y=0)=P(Y=0\mid X=0)=0.8$ and $P(Y=1)=P(Y=1\mid X=1)=0.9$. However then $P(Y=0)+P(Y=1)=1.7>1$. Contradiction.